# Discord bot that gives role to the user I react on

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make a discord bot that gives "Verified" role to users that I react on

Simply my channel is based on verifications, the user will send me a picture that I must verify, I want to react to the picture with ✅ to give him "Verified" role. Anyone can help me please ?

I don't know much about python, I'm still learning python with 0 coding knowledge but I tried to copy off some codes in hope that so

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id) # Get guild
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member out of the guild
    # The channel ID should be an integer:
    if payload.channel_id == 812510632360149066: # Only channel where it will work
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅": # Your emoji
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id= 1030951866370113599) # Role ID
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None: # If role exists
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
            print(f"Added {role}")
```

I tried to work around this code but I keep getting this error message>  member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member out of the guild
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 812510632360149066:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='verified')

        if role is not None:
            msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            member = msg.author
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('done')
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: It does work now but only on me, I tried with different users from mobile and it doesnt give them the role

Comment: Try replacing the `payload.user_id` with `payload.message_id`

Comment: FINALLY IT WORKS!!! thanks alot!! there's only 1 issue there in the code that I had to fix, msg = await *bot*.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
I didn't define bot as anything as I was using "client" instead, swapped it for bot and it worked smoothly ^^ thanks alot again

Comment: Hey! sorry for bothering ^^ is there a way to add to this code to remove a role ?

When I react it gives a new role, I want the bot to also remove old role

Comment: Yes. Make a second role variable and remove it with this: `await member.remove_roles(roleToRemove)`